# SQL PostgreSQL add attribute from polygon to all points inside polygon but keep all points not just those that fall inside polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have two tables, one with points and one with polygons "in a PostgreSQL database". I need to get the attributes from the polygons "status" to the points that fall inside the polygons and the result need to show all points that the point table consists of and not only those that fall inside the polygons. I also only want 1 or 2 attributes from the polygon layer but the point layer should have all attributes `*`. My goal is to later create a view.

I tried to get this work with an intersect command but the result only shows points that intersect, it doesn't show the other points. Here is the code I tried with

```sql
SELECT 
  pointlayer.*, 
  polygonlayer.name
FROM 
  schema_a.pointlayer,
  schema_a.polygonlayer
WHERE ST_Intersects(schema_a.pointlayer.geom, polygonlayer.geom);
```

I attached an image that might explain what I want better then my text. Notice that status in image says null for points outside, but it just a way of me showing you that the attribute should be empty.

[image: Image of what I want result to look like]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp)ing both tables on an exclusive condition - and the result set contains only pairs that satisfy this condition.

**I urge you to adapt the explicit [`JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) syntax; it will help you understand the set-theoretic outcome and allows for side-specific inclusion.**

That being said, you want to run a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to include rows of `pointlayer` that do not satisfy the join condition:

```sql
SELECT
  pt.*,
  py."name",
  py.status
FROM
  pointlayer AS pt
  LEFT JOIN
  polygonlayer AS py
    ON ST_Intersects(py.geom, pt.geom)
;
```

which can then also be used directly as *View* definition.

Comment: That worked great! But how can I join a third table to the points? I tried adding the third table that also consists of polygons to the st intersects but that wont work for me.

Comment: @esset no, that cannot work. The atomic relation in PostgreSQL is _binary_, meaning that a statement can only ever relate two database objects (e.g. joining two tables) - thus there is no function accepting more than two (columnar) parameters. **But of course you can join them *sequentially***, i.e. append another `LEFT JOIN otherpolygontable AS opy ON ST_Intersects(opy.geom, pt.geom)` (notice how this is another join on the `pointlayer` simply by specifying it in the condition) - the result set is a minimal row-set union over all three tables, with non-matching rows in `pointtable` included.